Google Pixel 8 random reboots fixed by debugging with Android Studio
I recently bought a refurbished Google Pixel 8 which was clearly unusable:
The phone rebooted each time I used a feature which was consuming some power (Start to view a video on youtube, Take a picture using the camera, Starting some apps,  calling someone ...)
These "reboots" are different from reboots using the power button:
The screen becomes black during a few seconds then the welcome screen is displayed again. There is no android nor google logo displayed before the welcome screen.
I applied all OS and apps updates and the problem was still there.
I started to debug the phone using logcat feature of Android Studio to see if there is some interesting information printed before such restart.
I did not do anything else and the problem disappeared !
I disabled the developer mode required to debug using Android Studio and the issue did NOT reappear.
What is the cause of these restarts ?
How Android Studio debugging can fix such issue ?

Were the developer settings available by default or did you had to enable them (and ADB)? Had you tested (when the problem was still present) if an USB connection to a charger or the PC have an impact on the reboot problem (or the battery percent level)?

I had to enable the developer settings to enable developer mode and then use adb.
When the problem was present USB connection to charger or PC had no impact.
